# Inverse Process of Label Binarisation in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have performed a label binarisation for multiclass classification and it is working fine:

```
y_test
1
3
4
2
0

from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

y_test_binarize = label_binarize(y_test, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y_test_binarize

0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   1
0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
```

Next, I would like to do an inverse process to get `y_test` from `y_test_binarize` variable.

Are there any predefined methods?

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer), which wraps the label_binarize function in a class and provides methods to transform to binary data and also inverse_transform them to original classes.

```
y_test = [1, 3, 4, 2, 0]

from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()

y_test_binarize = lb.fit_transform(y_test)
#Output: y_test_binarize
array([[0   1   0   0   0],
       [0   0   0   1   0],
       [0   0   0   0   1],
       [0   0   1   0   0],
       [1   0   0   0   0]])

y_test_original = lb.inverse_transform(y_test_binarize)
#Output: y_test_original
array([1, 3, 4, 2, 0])
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask if any problem.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to calculate the matrix product of the binarized data and the classes:

```
>>> classes = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> y_test_binarize.dot(classes)
array([1, 3, 4, 2, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using argmax functions of numpy:

```
np.argmax(y_test_binarized, axis=1)
```